# Fetching remote connections count

Tags: unix, tcp, connection

I want to create game server list and want to print how many players are playing on each server - I'll have to get count of TCP established connections (on specified port). Of course this is impossible without the interference of the server administrator...

I can create a script, which will send the connections count, and then I can give it to the search administrator to install, but its not a best idea, at the same, this is the best idea I got at the moment.

Maybe you have any better ideas on how can I get players count (tcp connections) from a remote server and display it on my server, both - mine and remote server will use FreeBSD for sure.

Let me know if you dont understand anything.

Comment: Do you have a shell account on the server?

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov On my server I do, but on the remote servers I dont.

Comment: All you need is the output of `netstat -np tcp | grep PORT` - can't you do something like `system(3)` from your own code?

Comment: what do you mean of the `system(3)`? As I said, that servers on my list are remote.

Comment: Do you run any of your own code there?

Comment: No, but I can make an annoucement for server administrator so if they want to display players count, they need to run any code first.

Comment: I would expect any system admin to know how to list active TCP connections.

Comment: Ask the admin to create a cron job to append that connection list to a file on, say, 15 minutes interval and have it emailed to you every so often.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov Aight, thanks :-). You can post an answer, so I could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the remote server administrator to create a [`cron`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=crontab) job to append the output of `netstat -np tcp | grep PORT` command to a file on, say, 15 minutes interval and have it emailed to you every so often.